# RegEx: match expression or nothing

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I'm trying to accomplish the following in regex.
Should match:

- any number of characters
- not a letter *or nothing at all (= beginning of string)*
- "on"
- letters
- spaces
- "="
- any number of characters

This is what I've got:

```
[^a-zA-Z]on([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s*?)=
```

The following are correct:

- **xonfoo=** does not match
- **0onfoo=** does match

The problem is that this *does not match but should*:

- **onfoo=**

How do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nate: it's encouraged to mention what you've tried when asking a question on SO

Comment: That's not what I meant. What I meant is that you currently have a problem X that you didn't clarify. You found solution Y, namely your regular expression, to solve it and want help with it. But it's possible (and in IT actually likely) that there is another solution Z that solves your problem as well, and does it better than your solution Y, either through easier maintenance, better performance or less likelihood for bugs. So could you update your question with what your problem X is?

Comment: @Nate: point taken. The question should've explain the context better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `\b` and a `?`:

```
\b[^a-zA-Z\s]*on([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s*?)=
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/kX7wD1/2

Comment: Why `\b`? There is no statement that it should be a word.

Comment: @pwas If you don't add the `\b` then `xonfoo=` will match. The OP doesn't want it to match.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. That fixes the problem in my original question. I failed to mention that any number of chars can precede the string, so `00onfoo=` should match as well. Would u happen to have a solution there?

Comment: @David I changed the regex slightly. But Nate seems right here, what's the task you're trying to resolve with this regex?

Comment: This is one of the rules of the ASP.NET built-in validation for "dangerous" strings. While I want to keep the validation, I'd like to catch it client-side and show a message next to the field, in stead of one ugly general exception from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[^a-zA-Z]?on([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s*?)=
```

Notice the first question mark. You were basically asking for exactly one non-letter character.

Comment: Making the first part optional (by adding the ?) causes `xonfoo=` to return a positive match, while it should not.

Comment: I see, but it will only match the string starting from onfoo, without the "x". Try this instead: ^[^a-zA-Z]?on([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s*?)= if you need to match the whole string. Otherwise, let me know how you're using it so i can help further.

Comment: The regex in the comment does fix the problem in my original question. I failed to mention that any number of chars can precede the string, so `00onfoo=` should match as well. Would u happen to have a solution there?

Comment: I'm assuming you need this to match the whole string, not to find this pattern in a larger string. Try this: ^[^a-zA-Z]*on([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s*?)=$ http://www.regexr.com/397nd